# Notepad++ Add Tags to second row

Tags: notepad++

Editing a HUGE list.

I've found how to replace most of what I need to not make it a huge ordeal, but I need to add an HTML link to each Second bit of information.

Right now the formatting is

dashes = Tabs.

Year - Name - Etc - Etc

So it looks like this:

2012 -     Mark -     Dept -     other

2010 -     Louanne -     Dept -     other

2009 -     Jannett -     Dept -     other

But I need to add formatting so it looks like this:

2012 -     [url=http://www.website.com/personell/Mark]Mark[/url] -     Dept -    other

2010 -     [url=http://www.website.com/personell/Louanne]Louanne[/url] -     Dept -     other

2009 -     [url=http://www.website.com/personell/Jannett]Jannett[/url] -     Dept -     other

is there any way to quickly do this in Notepad++?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it easily using regular expressions. Go to `Search > Replace` menu (shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) and do the following:

1. Find what:

   ```
   ^\d+\t\K(.+?)(?=\t)
   ```
2. Replace:

   ```
   [url=http://www.website.com/personell/$1]$1[/url]
   ```
3. Select radio button "Regular Expression"
4. Then press `Replace All`

You can test it live at [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/dW1qW9).

Comment: quote: `dashes = Tabs.` Meh, still, that's nice.

Comment: That did not work. Searching for ^\d+\t\K(.+?)(?=\t) Returns: "Can't find the text: ^\d+\t\K(.+?)(?=\t)"     Yes I set it to Regular Expression.

Comment: Works for me as you can see here http://regex101.com/r/dW1qW9! I can see only 2 reasons why this doesn't work for you: 1) you have a very old version of Notepad++ (mine is the latest v6.5) or 2) your data is actually delimited by [space][tab][space] and not by [tab] only as I thought. Let me know if this is it.

Comment: Notepad++ 5.9 I will try updating it. Thanks!

Comment: So I assume it worked, right?! From v6.0 Notepad++ changed its regular expression engine to PCRE that's why it didn't worked (http://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-6.0-release.html). Regarding the regex, to be honest I didn't provided you the easier to understand solution... Here's a simpler variant: http://regex101.com/r/xM2eI6

Comment: Yep it worked Perfectly once I updated Notepad++ thanks a lot! you saved me hours of work.